# Spring validation based on client IP

Tags: spring-mvc

I have got Spring Validator for form object in Spring MVC project and I need to do some validation which is partially based on client IP address. Is it possible to get something like request.getRemoteAddr()  inside the validator ?

```
//controler

public String saveForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("command") MyCommand myCommand, BindingResult result) {
//some code
return "viewName";
}

//Validator
public class MyValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    String requestIp = ?
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way which comes to my mind is to using [`RequestContextHolder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) to get user's request:

```
((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getRemoteAddr()
```

You also need to add following lines to `web.xml`:

```
<listener>                                                                                      
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: thank you very much, I should know that there will be some context holder for requests as I am using LocaleContexttHolder :-)